# How to design a rank with flexbox and page controllview

Tags: react-native, flexbox, rank

I'm trying to put the name's on the left and the rank on the right. I tryed the flexDirection row with a space between or space evenly but it still doesn't work.

[image]
Do you have any solution for that ?

Also my function :

```
 renderRanking = () => {
    return this.state.ranking.map((element) => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-’‘’',
          }}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white'}}>{element.club}</Text>

            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white'}}>
              {element.moyenne}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

And my render

```
render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
          <ScrollView>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
              }}>
              <Text>{this.OpenDecibels()}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{paddingBottom: 30}}>
              <PageControlView defaultPage={1}>
                <View>{this.renderRanking()}</View>
              </PageControlView>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-’‘’',
          }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white'}}>{element.club}</Text>

            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white'}}>
              {element.moyenne}
            </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Remove View tag with style={{
                flex: 1,
              }}

Answer (score 0):

You should try below snippet in your **renderRanking** function.

```
renderRanking = () => {
    return this.state.ranking.map((element) => {
      return (
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white'}}>{element.club}</Text>

            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'white'}}>
              {element.moyenne}
            </Text>
          </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

Also change

```
<PageControlView defaultPage={1}>
    <View>{this.renderRanking()}</View>
</PageControlView>
```

To

```
<PageControlView defaultPage={1}>{this.renderRanking()}</PageControlView>
```